# How can i change TextField border-radius in Mui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change mui `TextField` border radius but it's not working. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

`<TextField variant="outlined" sx={{ borderRadius: 5 }} />`

Can anyone fix it this?

Answer (score 2):

override `MuiOutlinedInput-root` clasee

```
 sx={{
      ".MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
        borderRadius: 5 
      }
    }}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
<TextField
    className="inputRounded"
    placeholder="Search"
    variant="outlined"
    size="small"
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more generic solution for all the textfields you can set the `borderRadius` for the `Textfield` in yourr theme. So you don't have to add and repeat the `sx` property on each one.

Here is the code in your theme file:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
              borderRadius: 5,
          },
        },
      },
    }
    }
  });
```

Or you can create a styled component like this:

```
import styled from "styled-components";    
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";

export const InputStyled = styled(TextField)`
  & .MuiOutlinedInput-root {
    border-radius: 10px; 
  }
`;

//Use it like this:
<InputStyled label="email" variant="standard" />
```